# Dynamically created Validation now enforced

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a dynamic element as such:

```
 strDivAttend += "<div class=\"row\" id=\"otherAttendee__" + i + "\"><div class=\"col-md-12\"><div class=\"col-md-3\"><div class=\"form-group\">";
 strDivAttend += "<label class=\"control-label required\" for=\"newAttendees_" + i + "__AttendeeName\">Attendee Name</label>";
 strDivAttend += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"newAttendees.Index\" value='" + i + "' /><input class=\"form-control text-box single-line\" data-val=\"true\" data-val-required=\"The Attendee Name field is required.\" id=\"newAttendees_" + i + "__AttendeeName\" name=\"newAttendees[" + i + "].AttendeeName\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" />";
 strDivAttend += "<span class=\"field-validation-valid text-danger\" data-valmsg-for=\"newAttendees[" + i + "].AttendeeName\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span>";
 strDivAttend += "</div></div>";
 strDivAttend += "<div class=\"col-md-3\" style=\"margin-top: 35px;\">";
 strDivAttend += "<a id=\"removeOtherAttend__" + i + "\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"removeButtonAttend\" style=\"color:#aaa;\"><i class=\"fa fa-times-circle\"></i>&nbsp; remove</a>";
 strDivAttend += "</div></div></div>";
$('#dvOtherAttendees').append(strDivAttend);
```

The problem that I am running into is that even though the dynamically created script has field validation in there, it is not enforced. Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side validation is initialized on initial page load, any elements added dynamically afterwards won't be validated unless you re-parse your document.

```
$('form').removeData('validator').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

Comment: Thank you. Where should this code go. I put it in  $(document).ready(function () and also when on click of when I added the dynamic content but it did not work.

Comment: @NatePet right after `$('#dvOtherAttendees').append(strDivAttend);`. Should work fine assuming the validation properties on the html you're injecting is correct.